# CCNA / OSPF / Area / Alternative Definition

Tags: ospf

Can another definition for an OPSF area be: A multicast domain within a larger autonomous system that is primarily subject to a single LSDB (topology database)?

//edit
I'll modify my definition soon.

Comment: I wouldn't base it on a multicast domain since that might have a different range - an OSPF area can be both larger and smaller than the actual multicast domain(s).

Comment: You can have an OSPF area that may only have some multicast links or does not use multicast at all. Only an OSPF link on a broadcast medium may use multicast, and an OSPF area probably includes many links. The link-local multicast that OSPF may use will not cross a router, so even if all the links are broadcast media, there could be many multicast domains in an OSPF area. On NBMA links, OSPF uses unicast, and it can even be configured to use unicast on a broadcast medium.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSPF isn't used for Multicast routing.  While it was defined in the standard to use LSA type 6, the implementation of routing multicast trafic via OSPF was proved to be flawed.  Cisco and other network vendors do not support OPSF routing of multicast traffic.
Don't confuse this from the OSPF usage of the 224.0.0.5/6 addresses.  These address are used on local segments (think individual subnet) for routers to establish neighbor relations and to exchange routing information.  The routing information exchanged is IP subnets for forwarding unicast IP traffic based on destination.  The do not exchange multicast routing information needed to locate the best path back to the source of a multicast sender.

TLDR: No, you cannot refer to an OSPF area as a "Multicast Domain," that would be an incorrect way to refer to OSPF areas.

Comment: The question isn't about multicast *routing*. It's about whether an OSPF area may be equal to a multicast domain.